# Is there any kind of consensus among experts about Direct Realism?

Tags: realism, naive-realism

I've been reading about Direct and Indirect Realism lately, and I came across this [Stanford Encyclopaedia article](https://plato.stanford.edu/Entries/perception-problem/#:%7E:text=This%20entails%20Direct%20Realism%20%E2%80%93%20that,built%20into%20perceptual%20experience%20itself.).

In the Conclusion section, the article ends with this: "The question, now, is not so much whether to be a direct realist, but how to be one." Given the reputation of Stanford Encyclopaedia on these kinds of topics, it would seem weird to me to end on such a strong leaning towards one side of the debate *unless* the debate really was settled, and there was a consensus among relevant experts.

On the other hand, this article was in fact written by one or a handful of people, and those people are certainly capable of concluding an article with their own personal beliefs.

So yeah, I would love to know if there's actually a real expert consensus on this topic.

Comment: Due to the fact that so-called Problem of Perception is debated (at least in the Western world) since Ancient Greek philosophers, no wonder IMO if there is no "consensus" on the different theories formulated to answer the issue.

Comment: A good book: John R. Searle, [Seeing Things as They Are: A Theory of Perception (Oxford University Press, 2015)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Seeing_Things_as_They_are/3jfvBQAAQBAJ)

Comment: Also Hilary Putnam, [Sense, Nonsense, and the Senses : An Inquiry into the Powers of the Human Mind (The Dewey Lectures 1994)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2940978)

Comment: I think you are reading too much into that sentence. The whole section it is in concerns debates *within* direct realism, all it says is that direct realists now spend more time debating each other rather than debating their detractors. According to [PhilPapers poll](https://philpapers.org/surveys/results.pl), more favor representationalism (31.5%) than variants of direct realism put together (26.3%), and a plurality chooses "other" (42.2%).

Comment: @Conifold that poll doesn't even look like it gives an option close to 'direct realism'. Perhaps some signification fraction of "other" include the direct realists? -- edit -- apparently disjunctivism is supposed to be the 'direct realism' option

Comment: @Conifold I'm really confused on this topic right now lmao. Many sources consider representationalism to be an indirect realist position. Many other ones say it's a direct realist position. This is ... kinda mind-boggling

Comment: You can choose more fine-grained version of responses at the top of the page, "other" are more of don't know/don't care variety. Other "direct realisms" are probably too scarce to register.

Comment: I want to put this here for future reference as well: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/89427/what-is-the-difference-between-qualia-theory-sense-datum-theory-and-representat -- @Conifold here, they also discuss a similar philpapers survey, but the question-asker and top answer seem to interpret some answers as 'indirect realism' which you seem to interpret as 'direct realism'. I find it very confounding that there's so much disagreement on whether or not a particular view is under indirect or direct realism - I'd think the answer to that would be more obvious.